# Adding title to TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, titlebar

I am trying to figure out how to add a simple title to my swift project. I have listed students in a tableview and just want to add a title in the center above the list that says "STUDENTS" and I can't figure it out for the life of me. Every time I attempt to add anything it either is in the way of the carrier settings or does not appear. He is my code for everything but an attempted Title block.

```
class StudentRosterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var studentsList = [Dictionary<String, String>]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let studentRoster = ClassRosterModel()
        studentsList = studentRoster.studentRoster
    }

// MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return studentsList.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StudentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel!.text = studentsList[indexPath.row]["name"]
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = studentsList[indexPath.row]["number"]

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are creating your UITableViewController **without** IB (Storyboard)

```
class StudentRosterTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(style: .Plain)
        self.title = "StudentRoster"
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

**With** storyboard find View Controller section and type your title there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you could go the way of setting a section title by implementing this method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> String?
{
  return "Students"
}
```

If you had several sections, you could use a switch statement over the section parameter and return the appropriate title for each case.

Comment: If i were to do that, it added it so it interferes with the Verizon label because it is too high is there a way to fix that?

Comment: you could resize the tableview in storyboard to avoid that

Comment: Thanks much appreciated, sorry if they seem like beginner questions, trying to grasp from my life of java.

Answer (score 2):

Set the title of your view controller:

```
 self.title = "some title"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
self.title = "Your View controller title"
```